# Convert python byte string to numpy int?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a direct way instead of the following?

```
np.uint32(int.from_bytes(b'\xa3\x8eq\xb5', 'big'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to get the right datatype.  To read big endian uint32 from a string the datatype (as a string) is `'>u4'`.

```
>>> np.fromstring(b'\xa3\x8eq\xb5', dtype='>u4')
array([2744021429], dtype=uint32)
```

This gives you an array back, but getting a scalar from there is a pretty trivial matter.  More importantly, it allows you to read a large number of these objects in one go (which you can't do with your `int.from_bytes` trick).

Comment: It was just for a hash value - for which I guess there's no advantage (actually a bit slower) - but for buffers this is much better.

Comment: Yeah, now I see the proper data type.

Answer (score 9):

Using `np.fromstring` for this is deprecated now. Use `np.frombuffer` instead. You can also pass in a normal numpy dtype:

```py
import numpy as np
np.frombuffer(b'\xa3\x8eq\xb5', dtype=np.uint32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the data type.

```
np.fromstring(b'\xa3\x8eq\xb5', dtype='<i')
```